# How do I filter Event Viewer down to errors from a single website?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, windows-event-log, eventviewer

I have used Event Viewer to create a custom view of all ASP.net errors by using the GUI as below

[image: filter to asp.net errors]

How do I create custom views for a single website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By going to the XML tab, there is a more detailed filter function. Add to the existing terms so that events only appear if the Application Path is mentioned. For example, if your events contain the information `Application Path: C:\inetpub\application-1\` you would alter the query to be:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
    <Select Path="Application">
      *[System[(EventID=1309) and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 604800000]]] 
      and
      *[EventData[Data and (Data="C:\inetpub\application-1\")]]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Answer (score 0):

In event viewer filter you are having an option to select the applications and process by their name from **"event source"** where you can select asp.net from the dropdown menu. Also you can specifically filter the exact errors by providing Event id's by using include/exclude Event ids options