# How to filter Event Viewer for a single website?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-event-log, eventviewer

I am trying to find out each concurrences for an error happening on a website I managed to create an XML query to filter by EventID

```
<QueryList>
<Query Id="0" Path="Application">
<Select Path="Application">
*[System[(EventID=1316)]] 
</Select>
</Query>
</QueryList>
```

This works fine and gives me a list of errors
[see filtering's results here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVkNn.png) Now I need to nail down to a particular website so [I found here](https://serverfault.com/questions/636657/how-do-i-filter-event-viewer-down-to-errors-from-a-single-website) an answer (that I can't comment) where I am trying to filter the Application Path but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my new XML filter

```
<QueryList>
<Query Id="0" Path="Application">
<Select Path="Application">
*[System[(EventID=1316) and  *[EventData[Data and 
 (Data="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\vps1138245.vps.myhosting.com\lafesta.cl\")]]]] 
 </Select>
 </Query>
 </QueryList>
```

This query gives me 0 row. What's wrong with my filter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
    <Select Path="Application">*[System[(EventID=1316)] and EventData[Data and (Data='C:\Inetpub\vhosts\vps1138245.vps.myhosting.com\lafesta.cl\')]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```